# handle flutter image.network no internet exceptions

Tags: flutter, image, exception

I am trying to handle no internet exception in my app but I can't handle image.network exception even that I used errorBuilder here is my code

```
Image.network(
              image!,
              fit: BoxFit.fill,
              errorBuilder: (BuildContext context, Object exception,
                              StackTrace? stackTrace) {
                            return noUserImage();
              },
          ),
```

the implementation of noUserImage

```
  Icon noUserImage() {
    return Icon(
      Icons.account_circle_rounded,
      size: 120,
      color: defaultColor,
    );
```

and this is the error that appear when ever I close the wifi connection
[image]

Comment: How about noUserImage implementation?

Comment: I  added it now it's just an icon